# How much has Obamacare cost Senate Democrats in public support?

Tags: united-states, senate, public-opinion

Early in November, [President Obama met with Senate Democrats](http://politicalticker.blogs.cnn.com/2013/11/06/obama-biden-meet-with-senate-democrats/) concerning the rollout of the Affordable care Act.

> A group of 15 Senate Democrats–all up for re-election in a year–met with President Barack Obama Wednesday to get an update on the beleaguered website where Americans are supposed to be able to register for exchanges created under the Affordable Care Act. [...]
>
> A congressional source with knowledge of a meeting between Obama and **the group of Democratic Senators told CNN concerns about the impact of Obamacare on next year’s mid-term elections were a part of the reason for the gathering** at the White House.
>
> “There would not have been this meeting if you didn’t have this group of Senators up in 2014,” the Democratic staffer with knowledge of the meeting told CNN.

**How much has Obamacare cost Senate Democrats up for reelection in 2014 in public support?**

I am not specifically interested in whether it was just the rollout of Obamacare, [80 million](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2013/11/26/evidence-shows-obama-administration-predicted-tens-millions-would-lose-plans/) or more people [losing their grandfathered healthcare plans](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/how-many-people-will-be-unable-to-keep-their-health-insurance-plan-in-2014-due-t), or other objections to Obamacare. Public opinion polls just before October 1, and after October 1 would be acceptable, or polls asking specifically about Obamacare and Senator approval/disapproval ratings would be preferred.

For example, [Kay Hagan lost 10%-15% points](http://www.politico.com/story/2013/11/kay-hagan-senate-poll-99731.html) versus various 2014 GOP candidates.

> Against state House Speaker Thom Tillis, Hagan leads by only 2 points, 44 percent to 42 percent, according to the Democratic firm Public Policy Polling. She leads the Rev. Mark Harris by 2 points [...] That’s a huge difference from PPP’s September poll, which gave Hagan leads of anywhere from 12 points to 17 points against all possible GOP challengers.

**Note:** I am specifically interested in the 15 or so Democrats that attended the meeting with Obama regarding the Affordable Care Act, but there are [21 Democrats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Senate_elections,_2014) up for reelection.

Comment: Didn't bother looking at the polls, but 538's qualitative statements seems to attribute  a LOT of 2014 election success to Obamacare's botched rollout (if not the entirety of Obamacare - but as you and I both know, the botched rollout was 100% intrinsically embedded in how that thing was engineered)

Comment: We don't know. We can't untangle it.